# Leer nombre archivos Apps Script y ordenarlos

Tags: google-apps-script

tengo una sheet de google para realizar Actas.
Cada acta es un número sucesivo de la anterior, que se guarda en la misma carpeta que la hoja de cálculo a modo de "0001 Asunto", "0002 Asunto"... etc.
Ahora tengo que mirar de manera manual en la carpeta cuál es el último acta (mayor número) y escribir el siguiente y guardarla así.
¿Cómo podría hacer para que leyese los archivos de la carpeta y buscase el número mayor y así escribir en el número de acta el que corresponde +1?
Todos los archivos de la carpeta son como indico arriba "0003 Acta", "0004 Asunto".

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.